# What do Public Enemy mean by the rap lyrics of Mind Terrorist?

Tags: song-lyrics

The lyrics to the rap *Mind Terrorist* by Public Enemy is as follows:

> Take that, ha ha, yeah boy
> Best for your face
> Take that, ha ha, yeah boy
> Best for your face

---

> Take that, best, best for your face
> Best for your face, best for your face
> Take that, ha ha, yeah boy
> Best for your face
>
> Take that, ha ha, yeah boy
> Best for your face

---

> Take that, ha ha, take that
> Take that, ha ha, take that
> Take that, ha ha, take that
> Best, best, best, best for your face

What on earth do these lyrics mean and what is the connection with the title - Mind Terrorist?